# How to use multiple UserDetailServices with one authentication manager in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring application that uses CAS to handle authentication and then looks up authorization details using LDAP. Going forward, I need to also check a database for additional user details and permissions, so that if they are not explicitly granted access through Active Directory security groups, I can determine access levels based on secondary information. I want to continue using CAS to handle all authentication.

I know how to configure an additional UserDetailService to look for information in the database, but how do I have Spring Security look at both services?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple UserDetailsService but rather, will probably want to look at using a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html

which will fire after successful authentication and from which you will do your additional database calls:

See here for an example:

http://javapointers.com/tutorial/spring-custom-authenticationsuccesshandler-example-2/